# Out put a bit off for method

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance, extends

So this class is inheriting things from other classes which when the client class is used will run all of this.

So far my output is

> Your drink choice was: The name of the drink :Black coffeeand its price is: 3.0and the size is :2

When I write in the parameters "Coffee coffee = new Coffee("Black coffee",1,2,"Mocha");" into the client class.

This isn't quite right and I also need to calculate the total but I can't figure out where I need to put that bit of code.

```
public class Drinks extends CoffeeShop {
    private String name; // default name
    private double price_per_oz= .10; // default price per oz
    private int size = 6;// default value

    public Drinks(){
        super();

    }
    public Drinks(String name,double price_per_oz,int size){
        this.name = name;
        this.price_per_oz = price_per_oz;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return ("The name of the drink :"+ name + 
                "and its price is: "+price_per_oz+
                "and the size is :"+ size );
    }
    public double getPrice(){
        return price_per_oz*size;
    }
    //getter setter

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice_per_oz() {
        return price_per_oz;
    }

    public void setPrice_per_oz(double price_per_oz) {
        this.price_per_oz = price_per_oz;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

inherited class:

```
public class CoffeeShop {
public CoffeeShop(){

}
public static void main (String [] args){
    Coffee coffee = new Coffee("Black coffee",1,2,"Mocha");
    Tea tea = new Tea ("Hot", 10,12, "Earl Grey");
}
```

}

coffee class:

```
public class Coffee extends CaffeinatedDrinks {
private String type="drip"; // default type

public Coffee(){
    super();
}
public Coffee(String name,double price_per_oz,int size,String type){
    super(name,price_per_oz,size);// inherit these from parent
    this.type = type; // make type available to use
    System.out.println(" "+"Your drink choice was:"+ " " + this);
}

public double getPrice(){
    if(6 == super.getSize()){ // if default size then use default price
        return super.getPrice();
    }
    else if(12 == super.getSize()){ // otherwise charge them more
        return super.getPrice()+0.5;
    }
    else{
        //must be the large 
        return super.getPrice()+1;
    }
}
```

}

Tea class:

```
public class Tea extends CaffeinatedDrinks {
private String flavor =" English Breakfast"; // default flavor 

public Tea(){
    super();//inherit parent class
}
public Tea (String name,double price_per_oz,int size,String flavor){
    super(name,price_per_oz,size);
    this.flavor = flavor;

    //define flavor in constructor method
    }
public double getPrice(){
    if(6 == super.getSize()){
        return super.getPrice();
    }
    else if(12 == super.getSize()){
        return super.getPrice();
    }
    else{
        //must be the large 
        return super.getPrice();
    }
}
```

}

Caffeinated drinks class:

```
public class CaffeinatedDrinks extends Drinks {
public CaffeinatedDrinks(){
    super();// inherit parent class Drinks

}
public CaffeinatedDrinks(String name,double price_per_oz,int size){
    super(name,price_per_oz*3,size);// take the price per oz from parent function and multiply it by 3
}
```

}

```
public class NonCaffeinatedDrinks extends Drinks {
public NonCaffeinatedDrinks(){
    super();// inherit parent class drinks

}
public NonCaffeinatedDrinks(String name,double price_per_oz,int size){
    super(name,price_per_oz*2,size);// take the price per oz from parent function and multiply it by 2
```

}
}

expected out put is something like this:
 Your drink order consists of:
water, size small, cost :$0.60
coffee, type mocha, size medium, cost: $2.30
tea, flavor earl grey size large, cost: $1.20
The total cost of your order is: $4.10

Comment: *"So this class is inheriting things from other classes which when the client class is used will run all of this"* ... yes.  Yes, you've explained your problem so very, very ... clearly.

Comment: Can you post the class it is inheriting from, and also post what your expected output is.

Comment: Sorry, but it's rather unclear what your actual question is.  Please show the actual output and the expected output for the case that's not working.  Also, where is the code for classes `Coffee`,  and `CoffeeShop`.

Comment: Drinks extending a coffe shop? LOL!

Comment: There's more code that you're not showing us (like the `Coffee` class). You've also not made very clear what you're asking exactly (you should include the desired output it side-by-side with the actual).

Comment: Where is the Coffee class? Does Coffee extend Drinks? Why Drinks extending CoffeeShop? Drink could extend glass etc. I don't know. But not the whole CoffeeShop.

Comment: The CoffeeShop class is supposed to be the client class that runs it all.